# where can i find a RADIUS configuration example of A cisco 2106 in combination with A juniper steel belted radius?

Tags: cisco, wifi, radius

I'm looking for a configuration example of a Cisco wireless lan controller in combination with a juniper steel belted radius appliance (used to be made by funk now acquired by Juniper).

It states in the release notes for the cisco wlan controller software that the product has been tested with Funk Steel-Belted RADIUS release 4.4.137 but i cant find any information on how to implement this.

Comment: Are you attempting 802.1x authentication (wpa/wpa2 infrastructure) or are you attempting mac authentication?

Also, is this a radius / SBR appliance or is an infranet controller?

Answer (score 1):

This is for IOS but might be useful, its for setting up CISCO IOS to authentication off of Juniper Steel Belted RADIUS.

http://www.davidstclair.co.uk/juniper-radius-cisco-ios

Its probably not what your looking for but might help set you along the right path, hope its helpful.